# Error when using AspectJ AOP with Java 7

Tags: spring, aspectj, java-7

I've updated Java to version "1.7.0_09-icedtea" (previously it was 1.6) and get the following message:

```
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate be
an class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error the 
@annotation pointcut expression is only supported at Java 5 compliance level or above
```

Application had been compiled with java 1.6 and compiler compliance level was set to 1.6 as well. I'm using spring 3.1.0

Has anyone been able to get aspectj working under Java 7?

Comment: What version of aspectj are you using?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

AspectJ 1.5.4 is not designed to work with Java7. Try upgrading your version of AspectJ to 1.7.0 or higher (latest was 1.7.2 as of this writing).

(I had [AspectJ/Java7 issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308447/how-do-you-configure-aspjectj-maven-plugin-to-use-java-7) before, too)

Comment: I changed aspectjweaver version to 1.6.12, now it works fine.

Comment: They've introduced _Java7 weaving support_ in 1.6.12 M2. But full support only comes from 1.7.0 RC 1, bugs are fixed in 1.7.1, so the latest 1.7.2 is advised. See the release notes: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-1612.html http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-170.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error. just compile your program with jdk 1.6 and run it with jre 6.
It will resolve your problem