# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException starting libreplan in docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, libreplan

I have a docker repo ([here](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/aquavitae/libreplan/)) with source code ([here](https://github.com/aquavitae/docker-libreplan)) that is supposed to start libreplan on a tomcat server.  There is a docker-compose.yml that sets it up.  However, when I start the container, I get a long list of java exceptions:

```
libreplan_1 | ERROR [01-June 05:01:53] [main] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
libreplan_1 | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '_filterChainProxyPostProcessor': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut methodWithinConcurrentModificationMarkedType
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:405)
libreplan_1 |   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:605)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:365)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4210)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:802)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:676)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:602)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:503)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:325)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1068)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
libreplan_1 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
libreplan_1 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
libreplan_1 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
libreplan_1 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
libreplan_1 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut methodWithinConcurrentModificationMarkedType
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
libreplan_1 |   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:87)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:98)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:83)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:105)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:281)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:791)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:762)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:399)
libreplan_1 |   ... 37 more
libreplan_1 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut methodWithinConcurrentModificationMarkedType
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
libreplan_1 |   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
libreplan_1 |   ... 57 more
libreplan_1 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut methodWithinConcurrentModificationMarkedType
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
libreplan_1 |   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor.getBus(BusExtensionPostProcessor.java:62)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(BusExtensionPostProcessor.java:53)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:350)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1331)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
libreplan_1 |   ... 66 more
libreplan_1 | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut methodWithinConcurrentModificationMarkedType
libreplan_1 |   at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:315)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:206)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:193)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:174)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:195)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:250)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:284)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:113)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:85)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:66)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.getEarlyBeanReference(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:271)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getEarlyBeanReference(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:645)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:464)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:185)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:166)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:206)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor.getBus(BusExtensionPostProcessor.java:62)
libreplan_1 |   at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(BusExtensionPostProcessor.java:53)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:350)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1331)
libreplan_1 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
libreplan_1 |   ... 80 more
```

I don't know java at all and I have no idea how to start debugging this.  Any advice?

Comment: Are you using Java 7 ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678417/error-when-using-aspectj-aop-with-java-7/15683358#15683358

Comment: It looks like I  am, the tomcat image uses Java7. I guess I'll have to find an alternative image that has an older version.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like if you update aspectjrt and aspectjweaver to 1.7.0 you will be fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how would I do that. Like I said I don't know Java at all. Is upgrading an apt-get thing or do I need to patch the source code?

Comment: I am assuming that libreplan has a pom.xml .. if so , can you post the Pom to your question ?

Comment: I found the pom.xml on github (https://github.com/LibrePlan/libreplan/blob/libreplan-1.4.0/pom.xml), but in doing so discovered that I'm using an outdated version.  Upgraded to 1.4 and that problem went away! Thanks for the help.