# Error the @annotation pointcut expression is only supported at Java 5 compliance level or above

Tags: java, spring, aspects

I am facing the same issue described in [Error when using AspectJ AOP with Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678417/error-when-using-aspectj-aop-with-java-7)

But provided solutions are not helping out.

1. I have upgraded spring-aspectjweaver & aspectjrt to 1.7.2
2. Increases the version of org.springframework.aspects to 3.2.1
3. Java 7
4. Tomact 6

I am using build.gradle to load it.

**Added Dependencies:**

```
compile(group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.7.2') 
compile(group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.7.2')
compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aspects', version: '3.2.1.RELEASE')
compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aop', version: '3.2.1.RELEASE')
compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '3.2.1.RELEASE')
compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-beans', version: '3.2.1.RELEASE')
compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '3.2.1.RELEASE')
compile(group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-expression', version: '3.2.1.RELEASE')
```

**Error stacktrace**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: **Error creating bean with name 'transfersComponent' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/.some path to jar ./com/barclays/internet/aggregate/component/TransfersComponent.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean** 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.config.internalEhCacheCachingAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut#0' while setting bean property 'pointcut'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheStaticMethodMatcherPointcut#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0' while setting bean property 'cacheAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.impl.CacheAttributeSourceImpl#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ehCacheManager' while setting bean property 'cacheManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ehCacheManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error the @annotation pointcut expression is only supported at Java 5 compliance level or above
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1429)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:631)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:568)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:295)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jul 16, 2015 9:50:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Comment: You can throw whatever library add it however if you don't tell the compiler to be 1.5 compliant or up it will give you this warning. You are using ant which by default sets the source/target to 1.4 I believe for the compile task (but that is a while ago). Also you haven't upgraded AspectJ only libraries using AspectJ.

Comment: @M. Deinum I have upgrade these three libraries :
1. spring-aspectjweaver
2. spring-aspectjrt
3. org.springframework.aspects
Do you want me to upgrade any other library ??

Comment: AspectJ you are nowhere mentioning the aspectj version. You are only upgrading related libraries not aspectj libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is solved, actually the project I am running consists of 3 modules. In two modules I was upgrading the jar version to 1.7.2, as only these two modules were using it.

But the third module also had the dependency, which was downloading the older version of spring-aspectweaver 1.5.3 and even after making changes in other two modules they were picking the old jar from module 1's dependency.

Removing the jar old dependency from the module and hard deleting the old jar helped.

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue.
the below link helped:

https://coderwall.com/p/8tbjdg/aspectj-complaining-about-java-5-compliance-level

I had to update the aspectj version and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have similar problem, I got this message when deploying to glassfish server:

error the @within pointcut expression is only supported at Java 5 compliance level or above.

It turn out due to one of my dependency was outdated. check your suspected dependency version. It is easier to spot if You have earlier working version and check only the additional dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If it is Eclipse, open the project properties>Java Compiler. Set the Compiler Compliance Level to 1.7.
For other IDE's, just google how to change the compiler compliance level.